# Whats the easiest way to make an antenna for a given radio

Tags: pcb, antenna

I am trying to make a PCB for the nrf8001(http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001). The IC has all the radio transceiver parts , however it requires an external antenna. Its small scale. A maximum of 50 pieces is all I will be needing. I was thinking whats the best approach I should take? Should I use a ceramic antenna or a PCB trace antenna. (Its for 2.4GHz and cost is definitely a factor which needs to be taken into consideration.)
Also I was wondering how the nrf24l01+ is available for such a low price. The IC is cheaper I agree , but for me to just make the board itself is extremely expensive  compared to the value of the entire breakout nrf24l01+ board? How do people achieve such low cost?([Ebay-Link which shows the low price of nrf24l01 breakout board -http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-NRF24L01-2-4GHz-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-For-Microcontr-/251044600998](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-NRF24L01-2-4GHz-Antenna-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-For-Microcontr-/251044600998))

I have also looked at https://github.com/nabilt/nRF8001-Breakout-Board but it seems to expensive for what I am looking for. Whats the best way for me to proceed?

Comment: Low cost = volume production in a favorable economy. Consider a usb charger might sell for 20 to 40 dollars in the US, while selling for 4 from china on ebay, and cost 40 cents in either case.

Comment: last months sometimes i did buy china-products from ebay. i bulid some aesure-device to connect to usb. first 5 pice did not work. second delivery some did work. then i buy the original product (35 euro than 8.90 euro) and all devices worked fine. the china distributos most do not send a invoice, they mostly write to package "gift", so i have no chance to do tax in a legal kind. cheap is verry expensive !